# django Like dislike isn't working in post list .but its working on post detail

Tags: django, post, django-templates

I cannot use the "is_liked" function in the forloop of home templates if else part. The post details views "is_liked" function works correctly. If the log in user like the particular post it will show dislike button. But i cant show the dislike button on the post lists. I have tried many ways to do that but can't find the solution.

"if is_liked else" part is not working on the home.html

home.html:

```
{% for post in posts %}

      <p><a class="article-content" href="{% url 'post-detail' pk=post.pk %}" >{{ post.content }}</a></p>
      <a href="{% url 'post-likes' pk=post.pk %}">
        {{ post.total_likes }}like{{ post.total_likes|pluralize}}
      </a>
      <form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% if is_liked %}
            <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ posts.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">dislike</button>
          {% else %}
          <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">like</button>
          {% endif %}

      </form>
      <a href="{% url 'post-detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.comments.count }}comment{{ post.comments.count|pluralize }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

post_detail.html:

```
<p>{{ posts.content }}</p>
<a href="{% url 'post-likes' pk=posts.pk %}">
{{ total_likes }}like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}
</a>
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if is_liked %}
<button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ posts.id }}" class="btn btn- 
  danger">dislike</button>
{% else %}
<button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ posts.id }}" class="btn btn- 
  primary">like</button>
{% endif %}
</form>
```

views.py:

```py
def post_detail(request, pk):
    posts = get_object_or_404(post, pk=pk)
    is_liked = False
    if posts.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked = True

@login_required
def like_post(request):
    posts = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    is_liked = False
    if posts.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        posts.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        posts.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True

    context = {'posts': posts, 'is_liked': is_liked, 'total_likes': posts.total_likes(), }


# postlist on views.py:


def post_list(request):
    posts = post.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'posts': posts, })
```

I have tried the is_liked value in the post list..but it was giving errors. I can't find the correct way to do that.

Comment: In your ```post_list``` you are not sending any ```is_liked``` value to your template. As it is an empty value the if / then part will never enter the ```True``` part

Comment: I cant do it the correct way. If you explain it it will be nice. Thank you

Comment: The questions seem incomplete here. Can you provide the models used in this example?

Comment: I cant do it the correct way. If you explain it it will be nice. Thank you @Chris

Comment: @Jack Ryan The basic approach form Jc Din is one possibility I think, but IMHO is annotation query is not correct for your use case. See my answer below

Comment: Does anyone know how to do that? @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Jc Din annotations are one approach. However, as your model seems to contain an `m2m field` IMHO we need to add some aggregation in order to make sure we only get distinct objects in our resulting queryset.

Try the following

```
    @login_required
    def post_list(request):
        # annotate `is_liked` field by checking if the current user is in the
        # record that liked the post other

        count_filter = Q(likes=request.user)
        like_case = Count('likes', filter=count_filter, output_field=BooleanField())

        posts = post.objects \
            .annotate(is_liked=like_case) \
            .all().order_by('-date_posted')

        return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'posts': posts, })
```

Then in your template where it says `{% if is_liked %}` change this to

```
{% if post.is_liked %}
```

Comment: If i import the Q and Count it still says TypeError at / 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable. The annotate(is_liked=like_case) \  problem.@Chris

Comment: @Jack Ryan Could you say exactly which line raises the error?

Comment: Do you also get an error if your are logged in as a user to your site?

Comment: posts = post.objects \
        .annotate(is_liked=like_case) \
        .all().order_by('-date_posted')

this line @Chris

Comment: no..If i log in as a user it shows me the result. but if i logged out it shows me the error

Comment: @Jack Ryan I can reproduce the error if I am not logged in. That is why I added the ```login_required decorator```.  Otherwise it works as expected - tested your view

Comment: ok..but that will be better if we show the postlist without log in required..but when they want to connect with the post liking or disliking they will have to login.@Chris

Comment: @Jack Ryan: I added the ```login_required decorator``` to my solution. I think users need to be logged in. Otherwise you cannot filter by user

Comment: Okay understood. Thank you very much.

Comment: But then you cannot tell which posts the user has liked and which not because Django does not know who the user is. What you can do is show als posts as not liked for anonymous users

Comment: Yeah thats right..i have added the @login_required too.@Chris

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide `is_liked` to your post_list response

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import BooleanField
from django.db.models import When, Case


def post_list(request):
    # annotate `is_liked` field by checking if the current user is in the
    # record that liked the post other
    like_case = Case(
        When(likes__in=[request.user], then=True),
        default=False, output_field=BooleanField())
    posts = post.objects \
        .annotate(is_liked=like_case) \
        .all().order_by('-date_posted')

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'posts': posts, })
```

there are other ways to solve this but I think having it in annotate works for now

Comment: so what will be the templates if else part. How should i call this in template

Comment: what do you mean by `if else part`? @JackRyan

Comment: i have to write the {% if is_liked %} and closing {% end if %} in the home template. So can i write the  {% if is_liked %} or i have to write {% if like_case %}. @Jc Din

Comment: @JackRyan oh, you need to access the `is_liked` in `post` so it would be `{% if post.is_liked %}`

Comment: its not working correctly. some posts getting the dislike and others don't after like the post. @Jc Din

Comment: @Jc Din Although I think annotations are a good approach to solve the problem I think your approach is not quite correct. As the ```post``` object contains an m2m field the resulting qs might contain multiple instance of one post. E.g. If post "A" has 3 likes from different users the resulting qs will contain 3 posts A, each with the annotation for a specific user.

Comment: exactly that is happening @Chris